# How to generate sitemap for pages generated dynamically in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, seo

My backend is in django. I can get post data from there and also post list.

In reactjs, I am just displaying post details and lists (and some more details related to posts...)

In reactjs my index.js file is as below

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { GoogleReCaptchaProvider } from "react-google-recaptcha-v3";

ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root"),
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

My app.js file is as below

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import HomePage from "./pages/HomePage";
import BlogPage from "./pages/BlogPage";
import "./css/styles.css";
import CategoryPostsPage from "./pages/CategoryPostsPage";
import SearchPage from "./pages/SearchPage";
import ContactPage from "./pages/ContactPage";

function App() {
  return (
    <main>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/post/:slug/" component={BlogPage} />
        <Route
          path="/category/:slug/"
          component={CategoryPostsPage}
        />
        <Route
          path="/query/:query/"
          component={SearchPage}
        />
        <Route path="/contact/" component={ContactPage} />
        <Route path="/" component={HomePage} />
      </Switch>
    </main>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I add new posts from backend (django admin panel).
And through API, react app gets data from backend.

I want to have all urls like
/post/some-slug
/post/some-slug-2
...
/
/contact/
...

This is for SEO purpose, When I search, it displays only homepage url and contact page url, not a single url for any post...

Please suggest, what should I do,
I have tried sitemap packages from npm, but doesn't seem working...

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem? I have an app with a similar structure and am curious how to get the post pages indexed

Comment: No answer yet. I found that if we want to be indexed in top, we should do advertisement once. This will index our pages for that time, and as traffic goes through the website, they visit some new pages (via links in the other pages)  and now new pages are also indexed...